# Java Tic Tac Toe Game Confirming Winner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, tic-tac-toe

Below is my code for a Tic Tac Toe game. There are two problems I am running into. For one, I am not sure how to return which player has won (X or O), I can just return if there is a winner. As well, when I try to run my program I can an out of bounds error. Where did I go wrong?

I have two files, one being TicTacToe and the other TTTBoard.

*TicTaeToe.java*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe
{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        TTTBoard board = new TTTBoard();

        System.out.println(board);

        Random gen = new Random();
        char player;
        if(gen.nextInt(2)==1)
            player = 'o';
        else
            player = 'x';
        while(!board.checkWinner() && !board.full()){

            System.out.println(player + " 's turn");
            System.out.println("Enter the row and column [1-3, space, 1-3]: ");
            int row = reader.nextInt();
            int column = reader.nextInt();    
            boolean success = board.placeXor0(player, row, column);
            if(!success)
                System.out.println("Error: cell already occupied!");
            else{
                System.out.println(board);
                if(player == 'x')
                    player = 'o';
                else
                    player = 'x';
                }
            }        
}
}
```

*TTTBoard.java*

```
public class TTTBoard{
    private char[][] board;

    public TTTBoard(){
        board = new char[3][3];
        reset();
    }

    public void reset(){
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                board[row][column] = '-';
        }
    public String toString(){
        String result = "\n";
        for(int row = 0; row <3; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                result += board[row][column] + " ";
            result +="\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
    public boolean placeXor0(char player, int row, int column){
        if(board[row -1][column -1]=='-'){
            board[row-1][column-1]= player;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    public boolean checkWinner(){
        return(checkRowsForWin()||checkColumnsForWin()||checkDiagnalsForWin());
    }

    public boolean full(){
        boolean full = true;
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
                if(board[row][column] == '-'){
                    full = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return full;
    }
    public boolean checkRowsForWin(){
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
                if(placeXor0(board[row][0], board[row][1], board[row][2]) == true){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkColumnsForWin(){
        for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
            if(placeXor0(board[0][column], board[1][column], board[2][column]) == true){
                return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkDiagnalsForWin(){
        return((placeXor0(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]) == true) || (placeXor0(board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]) == true));
        }    
}
```

New Code:

```
public class TTTBoard{
    private char[][] board;

    public TTTBoard(){
        board = new char[3][3];
        reset();
    }

    public void reset(){
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                board[row][column] = '-';
        }
    public String toString(){
        String result = "\n";
        for(int row = 0; row <3; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                result += board[row][column] + " ";
            result +="\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
    public boolean placeXor0(char player, int row, int column){
        if(board[row -1][column -1]=='-'){
            board[row-1][column-1]= player;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    public boolean checkWinner(){
        return(checkRowsForWin()||checkColumnsForWin()||checkDiagnalsForWin());
    }
    /*public String getWinner(){
        for(int row = 0; row <3; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            }
        }*/
    public boolean full(){
        boolean full = true;
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
                if(board[row][column] == '-'){
                    full = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return full;
    }
    public boolean checkRowsForWin(){
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
                if(board[row][0]== board[row][1]&& board[row][0]== board[row][2]){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkColumnsForWin(){
        for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
            if (board[0][column] == board[1][column] && board[0][column] == board[2][column]) {
                return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkDiagnalsForWin(){
        return((board[0][0]== board[1][1]&& board[0][0] == board[2][2]) || (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2]== board[2][0]));
        }


}
```

Comment: We need more information. How about the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @MihirSinghalException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 44
 at TTTBoard.placeXor0(TTTBoard.java:26)
 at TTTBoard.checkRowsForWin(TTTBoard.java:55)
 at TTTBoard.checkWinner(TTTBoard.java:35)
 at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:19)

Comment: @MihirSinghal I think if I make a getWinner function in the TTTBoard class, and replace board.checkWinner() with board.getWinner(), it should work (The function of getWinner would return if the player X or O is the winner).

Comment: Your issue is with the line `if(placeXor0(board[row][0], board[row][1], board[row][2]) == true)`. The 2nd and 3rd numbers are supposed to be row or column numbers, but you're passing characters (`'X'` or `'O'`)

Comment: @MihirSinghal Im confused what the problem is. In the line public boolean placeXor0(char player, int row, int column), should I use different parameters?

Comment: You should not be passing `board[row][1]`, which is a char, as the argument `row`, which wants an `int`, in placeXorO.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the line `if(placeXor0(board[row][0], board[row][1], board[row][2]) == true)`? From what I gather, `placeXor0` is for placing `X` or `O` on the board, not for checking to see if a spot on the board has an `X` or `O`. So you should be using a different method in order to check this. You have to do a similar thing for `if(placeXor0(board[0][column], board[1][column], board[2][column]) == true)`.

Answer (score 0):

In `checkRowsForWin`, you have the lines of code:

```
if(placeXor0(board[0][column], board[1][column], board[2][column]) == true) {
    return true;
}
```

You want to replace this with:

```
if (board[0][column] == board[1][column] && board[0][column] == board[2][column]) {
    return true;
}
```

And do a similar thing for `checkColumnsForWin` and `checkDiagnalsForWin`

Comment: I changed all three functions, but now when I run the program, it skips over the rest of the code and exits the program. I think its due to the fact that the board is created with every space being '-', and since these chars are equal in columns, rows and diag, it sets it to be true, and exits the program. I guess my next question is how do I print it so that the board switches the char it prints every other time. (Ex: Top part of board now =     --- and the one I want is +-+ so that it doesnt skip over the rest of the code.

Comment: Or is there another reason for this? (I also added the new code)

Comment: Instead of just dumping code in an answer, you should *explain* what is wrong and why the things you suggest have to be done.

Comment: @IngoBürk Any chance you could give me some insight?